# Cache downloads across EC2 slaves

Tags: caching, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ansible

For building a website, I run a Jenkins configuration consisting of a master which provisions and boots a (number of) EC2 slaves using Ansible. The slaves then execute the jobs.
For each of the jobs, several hundred Megabytes of data need to be downloaded (`npm install`, `bower install`). While the downloads are cached in the home directory of the user who executes the jobs on the slaves (in `~/.npm`, `~/.cache/bower/`), those caches are lost as soon as the slave is shut down.

What would be a good way of avoiding the repeated downloads from third-party sources?

Answer (score 1):

Both NPM and Bower have packages available to make a private repository cache that falls back to public repositories when necessary:

- NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia
- Bower: https://www.npmjs.com/package/private-bower